# Calculate period based on the dates given

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I have certain dates in Column O from O5 to O1200. I need to identify which period this date falls in and then return the period in Column AO frOM AO5 to AO1200. The data range for different periods are given in the picture below.

[Data range for different periods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djbue.png)

I was initially using a formula to calculate it but I want to automate the process. The code is as below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B5)=TRUE,"",IF(ISBLANK(O5)=TRUE,"Missing PSD",@IFERROR(IFS(
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$3,O5<=Calendar!$C$3),"P01",
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$4,O5<=Calendar!$C$4),"P02",
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$5,O5<=Calendar!$C$5),"P03",
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$6,O5<=Calendar!$C$6),"P04",
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$7,O5<=Calendar!$C$7),"P05",
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$8,O5<=Calendar!$C$8),"P06",
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$9,O5<=Calendar!$C$9),"P07",
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$10,O5<=Calendar!$C$10),"P08",
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$11,O5<=Calendar!$C$11),"P09",
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$12,O5<=Calendar!$C$12),"P10",
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$13,O5<=Calendar!$C$13),"P11",
AND(O5>=Calendar!$B$14,O5<=Calendar!$C$14),"P12"
),IF((DATE(2019,10,1)-O5)>0,"FY20 or before",IF((DATE(2019,10,1)-O5)<0,"FY22+","")))))
```

As mentioned, I want to automate this process and do the calculations on VBA instead of inserting the formula in the excel column.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: So does column O contain errors? If so how are you calculating the `DATE(2019,10,1)-O5)` if O5 is an error?

Comment: No, column O does not contain errors. If  DATE(2019,10,1)-O5)>0 then it is part of the previous accounting year and if it is DATE(2019,10,1)-O5)<0  then it is part of the next accounting year. We only want to focus on the periods in the current accounting year. Therefore we are mentioning FY20 or before or FY+. But for the dates within the current accounting year, I want to display the period.

Comment: The formula you gave looks good to me, why use VBA tho?

Comment: First of all why don't use a loop to run through O5 to O 1200. You subtract 5 from 2019/10/1 can you clear this thnigs.?

Comment: I am not subtracting 5. I am subtracting the date in "O5" column. This formula is just the formula I input in AO5 column. I want it to be a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this. I think I have it right.
Note to change the sheet name for the sheet that your dates and output is in as you don't have it mentioned in your question.

Another note: The i2 = 3 to 14 is your calendar list range. Change as needed I just based it on your formula. As well as column "A" in the calendar sheet having the "PO" values which this code uses to get the value.

```
Dim i1 As Long, i2 As Long, Cal As Worksheet, Data As Worksheet, OldDate As Date

Set Cal = Sheets("Calendar")
Set Data = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Need to change this to the sheet with the dates/output
OldDate = DateValue("1 Oct, 2019")

For i1 = 5 To 1200 'Your range of dates
    If Data.Range("B" & i1) <> "" Then
        If Data.Range("O" & i1) = "" Then
            Data.Range("AO" & i1) = "Missing PSD"
        Else
            For i2 = 3 To 14 'Your range within the Calendar sheet your are checking against
                If Data.Range("O" & i1) >= Cal.Range("B" & i2) And Data.Range("O" & i1) <= Cal.Range("C" & i2) Then
                    Data.Range("AO" & i1) = Cal.Range("A" & i2)
                    GoTo Nexti1
                End If
            Next i2
            If OldDate - Data.Range("O" & i1) > 0 Then
                Data.Range("AO" & i1) = "FY20 or before"
            ElseIf OldDate - Data.Range("O" & i1) < 0 Then
                Data.Range("AO" & i1) = "FY22+"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Nexti1:
Next i1
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I am getting the required output. But what if I want to save the dates within VBA? I actually want to delete the calendar sheet and have the date values with its period values stored in the VBA module.

Comment: That requires a lot more work and I'm not wanting to spend the time on that. It will also make the code a lot bigger to accommodate you having to state each date then also the "PO" values. This can be done in an array but again it isn't a smaller task that I'm not quite up to. May I suggest instead of removing the calendar you simply hide the sheet, therefore it's not in your way and you can always go back to it in the future. The code still works with the sheet hidden and if it didn't, we can unhide/rehide it in the code.

Answer (score 2):

By using a generic function (below), you don't even need the date range table, as the period can be calculated directly from any date. Then your formula becomes:

```
=FinancialPeriod(CellReferenceWithDate)
```

```vb
Option Explicit

    Public Const MaxWeekdayCountInMonth As Integer = 5
    Public Const DaysPerWeek            As Long = 7

' Returns the financial period of a calendar date.
'
' 2020-09-20. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function FinancialPeriod(ByVal Date1 As Date) As String

    Const FirstPeriod   As Integer = 1
    Const LastPeriod    As Integer = 12
    Const FirstMonth    As Integer = 10
    Const FirstDay      As Integer = 1
    Const MaximumDay    As Integer = 25
    Const Occurrence    As Integer = 4
    Const PeriodFormat  As String = "\P00"
    
    Dim YearStart       As Date
    Dim PeriodEnd       As Date
    Dim Period          As Integer
    
    YearStart = DateSerial(Year(Date1) - Abs(Month(Date1) < FirstMonth), FirstMonth, FirstDay)
    For Period = FirstPeriod To LastPeriod - 1
        PeriodEnd = DateWeekdayInMonth(DateAdd("m", Period - 1, YearStart), Occurrence, vbFriday)
        If Day(PeriodEnd) > MaximumDay Then
            PeriodEnd = DateAdd("ww", -1, PeriodEnd)
        End If
        If Date1 <= PeriodEnd Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    
    FinancialPeriod = Format(Period, PeriodFormat)
    
End Function

' Calculates the date of the occurrence of Weekday in the month of DateInMonth.
'
' If Occurrence is 0 or negative, the first occurrence of Weekday in the month is assumed.
' If Occurrence is 5 or larger, the last occurrence of Weekday in the month is assumed.
'
' If Weekday is invalid or not specified, the weekday of DateInMonth is used.
'
' 2019-12-08. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateWeekdayInMonth( _
    ByVal DateInMonth As Date, _
    Optional ByVal Occurrence As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal Weekday As VbDayOfWeek = vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) _
    As Date
    
    Dim Offset          As Integer
    Dim Month           As Integer
    Dim Year            As Integer
    Dim ResultDate      As Date
    
    ' Validate Weekday.
    Select Case Weekday
        Case _
            vbMonday, _
            vbTuesday, _
            vbWednesday, _
            vbThursday, _
            vbFriday, _
            vbSaturday, _
            vbSunday
        Case Else
            ' vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, zero, none or invalid value for VbDayOfWeek.
            Weekday = VBA.Weekday(DateInMonth)
    End Select
    
    ' Validate Occurence.
    If Occurrence < 1 Then
        ' Find first occurrence.
        Occurrence = 1
    ElseIf Occurrence > MaxWeekdayCountInMonth Then
        ' Find last occurrence.
        Occurrence = MaxWeekdayCountInMonth
    End If
    
    ' Start date.
    Month = VBA.Month(DateInMonth)
    Year = VBA.Year(DateInMonth)
    ResultDate = DateSerial(Year, Month, 1)
    
    ' Find offset of Weekday from first day of month.
    Offset = DaysPerWeek * (Occurrence - 1) + (Weekday - VBA.Weekday(ResultDate) + DaysPerWeek) Mod DaysPerWeek
    ' Calculate result date.
    ResultDate = DateAdd("d", Offset, ResultDate)
    
    If Occurrence = MaxWeekdayCountInMonth Then
        ' The latest occurrency of Weekday is requested.
        ' Check if there really is a fifth occurrence of Weekday in this month.
        If VBA.Month(ResultDate) <> Month Then
            ' There are only four occurrencies of Weekday in this month.
            ' Return the fourth as the latest.
            ResultDate = DateAdd("d", -DaysPerWeek, ResultDate)
        End If
    End If
    
    DateWeekdayInMonth = ResultDate
  
End Function
```

I have uploaded a demo with a year's dates for download [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AmcbXlHdG3aahokKV52XJL2VCxo1Iw?e=p6epBK).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will check it out!